# Where to report bugs against packages from ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa?

Tags: nvidia, ppa, bug-reporting

I know that bugs of software of `ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa` ought to be reported using `ubuntu-bug [package]` and adding the `[xorg-edgers]` prefix to the title, but I don't find any information for the mentioned PPA, [there's no "Report bug" function on launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers) and using `ubuntu-bug [package]` doesn't work for packages which aren't available yet, like `nvidia-381`.

Comment: Maybe email the repo owner and ask? See https://launchpad.net/~mamarley.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support for the proprietary nvidia driver from Ubuntu, you need to file a bug with Nvidia

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/522835/linux/if-you-have-a-problem-please-read-this-first/

That ppa is provided for testing only and is unsupported. From https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XorgOnTheEdge

> Warning: This is for testing only! Expect to screw up your X if you
>   try this out. This page is meant to help testing of new upstream
>   versions, to see if they fix Ubuntu bugs. If they do, a fix might be
>   backported to the official packages, or they will be available in the
>   next Ubuntu release.